# Proof that a factorization domain is a unique factorization domain if and only if every irreducible element is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

Today in algebra class my professor proved, among other things, that a factorization domain is a unique factorization domain if and only if every irreducible element is prime. I had a hard time following his proof, because he was explicitly juggling with units and their inverses all over the place. After class, I came up with a completely unit-free proof, given below. My question is: Are there any advantages to explicitly manipulating units, compared to my treatment?

---

**Preliminaries:** Let $D$ be a domain. Let $\sim$ be the association relation, i.e., the largest equivalence relation that implies divisibility.

**Definition:** A *factorization* for $n \in D$ is a finite multiset $S$ of irreducible elements such that $n \sim \prod S$.

**Definition:** Two factorizations $S$ and $T$ for $n \in D$ are *equivalent* if there exists a bijection $f : S \to T$ such that $p \sim f(p)$ for every $p \in S$.

**Definition:** A *factorization domain* is a domain such that every nonzero element admits a factorization.

**Definition:** A *unique factorization domain* is a domain such that every nonzero element admits a unique factorization up to equivalence.

**Theorem:** A factorization domain $D$ is a unique factorization domain if and only if every irreducible element is prime.

*Proof:* Assume $D$ is a unique factorization domain. Take nonzero elements $p,a,b \in D$ such that $p$ is irreducible and $p \mid ab$. There exists a nonzero element $h \in D$ such that $hp = ab$. Let $H,A,B$ be factorizations for $h,a,b$, respectively. Hence $\prod H \cdot p \sim \prod A \cdot \prod B$. By the unique factorization property there exists a bijection $f : H \sqcup \{p\} \to A \sqcup B$ such that $q \sim f(q)$ are associates for every $q \in H \sqcup \{p\}$. In particular, either $f(p) \in A$ or $f(p) \in B$. In the former case, $p \sim f(p) \mid \prod A \sim a$. In the latter case, $p \sim f(p) \mid \prod B \sim b$. Hence $p$ is prime.

Conversely, assume every irreducible element of $D$ is prime. Let $S$ and $T$ be factorizations of a common element. By induction on the cardinality of $S$, we have two cases:

- If $S = \emptyset$, then $\prod S = 1$, hence $\prod T \in D^*$, hence $T = \emptyset$.
- If $p \in S$, then $p \mid \prod T$. Since $p$ is prime, there exists $q \in T$ such that $p \mid q$. Since $q$ is irreducible, $p \sim q$. Let $S' = S \setminus \{p\}$ and $T' = T \setminus \{q\}$. Then $p \cdot \prod S' \sim q \cdot \prod T'$. By the inductive hypothesis, $S'$ and $T'$ are equivalent, hence so are $S$ and $T$.

Comment: This is fine, you understand it perfectly.